# Java: how to avoid NPE in ternary operator, in general how to perform null-checks elegantly?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null-check

Yesterday I had to write an ugly piece of code, in order to perform many null-checks on the fields of an object, in order to avoid NPE from ternary operator construct.

The problematic piece of code:

```
ResourceThresholds rt = getThresholdsFromConfig();
Thresholds defaultPerContainer = getDefaultThresholds();
    
return new Thresholds((!rt.getCpu().equals("")) ? Long.parseLong(rt.getCpu()) : defaultPerContainer.getCpu(),
           (!rt.getMemory().equals("")) ? Long.parseLong(rt.getMemory())  : defaultPerContainer.getMemory(),/*omitted for brevity*/);
```

I get a NPE on  `defaultPerContainer.getCpu()`, because the field `cpu = null`.
And this is fine, Java works the way it works.
Why I didn't just defaulted the field `Long cpu = 0L;` ? Because I need the `null` value as an indicator that we do not set any value.

The final functional variant of this particular piece of code ended up being:

```
        Long cpuVal;
        if (!rt.getCpu().equals("")) {
            cpuVal = Long.parseLong(rt.getCpu());
        } else {
            cpuVal = defaultPerContainer.getCpu();
        }
        Long memory;
        if (!rt.getMemory().equals("")) {
            memory = Long.parseLong(rt.getMemory());
        } else {
           memory = defaultPerContainer.getMemory();
        }
        //... many similar if-elses that give me the desired value;
        //which is really ugly, and I believe I am not the only one hitting this.
        return new Thresholds(cpuVal, memory..);
```

This code works as I needed to work but it is ugly!

Q1: Can someone hint me on whether I can find a way of using `Optional<T>` to resolve the NPE in the first variant with the ternary operator? Because this snippet works: `!rt.getCpu().equals("")) ? Long.parseLong(rt.getCpu()) : null` i.e. if I explicitly put `null` as a value, I get `null` when the condition is met.

In general, is there any elegant Java 8+ way to deal with this?

Q2: how do you optimize the glorious if-else construct for null-checking?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem java.lang.Long

Comment: OK I think I know what's happening.  Do you still get the problem if you change the part between the `?` and the `:`  to `new Long(rt.getCpu())` at all?  If that fixes it, it's because the ternary operation causes both the "true" and the "false" part to be interpreted as `long` instead of `Long`.

Comment: I am still getting the NPE, the logically correct 3rd operand would be ((Long) defaultPerContainer.getCpu()). In general, I think that you cannot cast null? ( defaultPerContainer.getCpu() returns null! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the ternary expression `A ? B : C`, if `B` and `C` are both compatible numeric types, but one is the *boxed object* and the other is a *primitive*, most people would think the result is boxed, by auto-boxing the primitive.

That is not the case. The ternary operator instead unboxes the object, so they are both primitives, and the result is then a primitive.

Which means that the following are the same:

```java
long B = ...;
Long C = ...;

Long R = ... ? B : C;

Long R = (Long) (... ? B : (long) C);
```

The result is that if `C` is null, you get NPE.

One way to fix it is to force auto-boxing of `B`:

```java
Long R = ... ? (Long) B : C;
```

With that change, a null `C` value will simply set `R = null`.

In the case in the question, `B` is `Long.parseLong(rt.getCpu())`, so instead of adding a cast to force auto-boxing, **use [`long.valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)** instead.

Also, unrelated, use `isEmpty()` instead of `equals("")`, and there's no need for parentheses around `A`.

Change the code to:

```java
return new Thresholds(!rt.getCpu().isEmpty() ? Long.valueOf(rt.getCpu()) : defaultPerContainer.getCpu(),
                      !rt.getMemory().isEmpty() ? Long.valueOf(rt.getMemory())  : defaultPerContainer.getMemory(),
                      /*omitted for brevity*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no `null` checks in the code snippet.
2. It's better to implement a simple utility method and use it when setting `cpu` and `memory`, and use Joda condition `"".equals(val)` to prevent NPE if `val` is `null`
3. To avoid unboxing, use `Long.valueOf` instead of `Long.parseLong` which returns primitive `long`:

```java
public static Long getValue(String val, Long defaultValue) {
    return "".equals(val) ? defaultValue : Long.valueOf(val);
}

Long cpuVal = getValue(rt.getCpu(), defaultPerContainer.getCpu());
Long memory = getValue(rt.getMemory(), defaultPerContainer.getMemory());
```

---

It is also possible to provide an overloading utility method using supplier of arguments and then pass the method references to it:

```java
public static Long getValue(Supplier<String> str, Supplier<Long> defVal) {
    return getValue(str.get(), defVal.get()); // calling implementation above 
}

Long cpuVal = getValue(rt::getCpu, defaultPerContainer::getCpu);
Long memory = getValue(rt::getMemory, defaultPerContainer::getMemory);
```

Comment: **`NullPointerException`** when `defaultValue = null`. --- Moving the code to a helper method doesn't do anything if you don't fix the actual problem. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822543/5221149) for actual problem.

Comment: Agree, prevented NPE by avoiding unboxing.  Hopefully, `defaultPerContainer` in the question is not null.

Comment: *Curious:* What's the point on the `Supplier` version?

Comment: If `defaultPerContainer` is null, then the fix in the question using `if` statements wouldn't work, so that is not the case.

Comment: @Andreas, just an example that a function can be used instead of the value